# How can you get the subviews of a custom UIView to appear in the Document Outline?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xib

If you create a custom UIView with a Xib file and add the custom UIView to Storyboard, the subviews inside the custom UIView do not appear in the Document Outline.

How do you get the subviews of the custom UIView to appear in the Document Outline?

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Apple Attributes Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html) if you're using Swift.If you're using OC,I suggest you use VVDocument.